# Why uses South to do migration in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-south, django-1.6

I am maintaining a Django project in version `1.6.X`. I had found some doubt and issue a question here.

As my known, Django from version `1.7` is able to do migration. And, I started to get Django it is version `1.7`. Its built-in scripts have migration. Therefore, I have no experience about doing migration by `South`.

So, I have a question. When Django hasn't migration before `1.7`, the Django project adopt `South` as migration solution. Right?

If I update the Django project to version `1.7.x`, may I deprecate `South`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use South as a migration alternative for a Django 1.7 project. Although it's recommended that you use the Django built-in migration functionality; you said yourself: you're more familiar with the Django built-in than with South.

The Django documentation has an excellent guide to upgrade from South:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/#upgrading-from-south

Follow the guide and you can remove South's dependency from the project.